# Java Socket connection getHostName

Tags: java, sockets

I am testing on java.net.ServerSocket.
What I want is the following.
When connecting to aaa.com, you get aaa.com,
Getting bbb.com when connecting to bbb.com.

My etc/hosts file configuration is as follows.

```
127.0.0.1 aaa.com
127.0.0.1 bbb.com
```

I used the following java source.

```
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);
Socket request = server.accept();
request.getInetAddress().getHostName();
```

And when connecting to aaa.com, aaa.com is returned.
When connecting to bbb.com, aaa.com is returned.

How can I get bbb.com when connected to bbb.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is not *connecting to* anything.  It is *accepting connections from* ... something.

So ... I presume that you have some client code (not shown) that is connecting to port `port` using hostnames "aaa.com" and "bbb.com" respectively.  And you want *this* server side to know which hostname that the client side used.

It is not possible.

The client resolves the hostnames to an IP address and then makes the connection using the IP address (and *only* the IP address).  Since the IP address is the same in both cases, the server side cannot distinguish the two cases.

---

It follows that if the application level of the server needs to know the hostname that the client used to make the connection, then the *application* protocol must pass this information from the client to the server.  (That is what protocols like HTTP, FTP and so on do.)

Comment: I was mistaken for something. Thank you very much. I'm going to try again.